# Why mac terminal screen gives me different characters then pyserial?

Tags: python, character-encoding, serial-port, encode

I'm trying transfer a .jpeg image from one device to another using serial communication. If I use mac built-in screen command in terminal

```
screen /dev/cu.usbserial-6 115200
```

I get correct .jpg image starting with the right header

```
ÿØÿàJFIF
```

But if I use pyserial, I get

```
Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã JFIF
```

Python receiving code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-5', 115200)

while True:
    s = ser.read(1)

    try:
        print(s.decode('charmap'), end='')
    
    except:
        pass
```

I believe it has something to do with encoding but I'm not sure what. All the non-exteded ascii values are the same in screen and pyserial.

If I convert "ÿØÿàJFIF" on website https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html, in ASCII encoding, it gives me correct start values for .jpeg

FF D8 FF E0 4A 46 49 46

but if I do it in UTF-8, it gives me

C3 BF C3 98 C3 BF C3 A0 4A 46 49 46

which has the same start as the value from pyserial in ASCII

Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã JFIF
C3 BF C3 98 C3 BF C3 20 10 4A 46 49 46

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong.

Thank you

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case: `print('ÿØÿàJFIF'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252'))` returns `Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã JFIF`…

Comment: Do you know how to reverse the process?  How to get ÿØÿàJFIF from Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã JFIF ?

Comment: or preferebly how to set up pyserial so it reads as screen command in terminal?

Comment: Image data is binary, so I don't think that applying text encodings is helpful here.  Try printing the actual bytes that you receive (use `bytes.hex()` if you prefer hex).

Comment: Well, yeah, it's binary composed of bytes. Every JPEG starts with FF D8 FF values. The weird thing is that bytes.hex() gives me wrong values aswell.
The question is actually not about .jpeg itself. It's aboyt why terminal screen gives me different hex values than pyserial. I believe it's the pyserial decoding.